# Java Android apache poi error 'functionMetadata.txt' not found on release file

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi, release

In my android application, I use poi apache to create an excel file.

I got the library from this [link](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/releases).

In file **build.gradle** include the library:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  files('libs/poishadow-all.jar')
  ...
}
```

When I check a debug file I do not get an error.

But when I check a release file I get the next error:

> resource 'functionMetadata.txt' not found

I noticed that this is somehow related to the following code:

```
float resSum = 15.12478;
cell.setCellFormula("ROUND(" + resSum + ", 2)");
```

The program crash in the line `cell.setCellFormula("...formula...")`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How are you building your program, and how are you including Apache POI in the resultant apk? Looks like you might be loosing some of the POI data files in the process is all

Comment: @Gagravarr, thank you for your time. I edit my post. I do not understand why is not work? I do it all via instruction.

Comment: have you find solution of it?

Comment: @AbdurRehman Hi. No. I do not have the solution. But I work now for this. If you want to include it, you can write me at Matatov1989@gmail.com